# draggingSession:sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext: Not Called

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I have a NSTableView controlled by a NSViewController.  They are within a NSWindow associated with a NSWindowController and associated with an NSDocument.  It performs a NSDragOperationCopy without difficulty.  I added a

`draggingSession:session sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:`

method in order to begin controlling move vs copy vs delete operations as follows:

```
-(NSDragOperation)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:(NSDraggingContext)context
{
switch(context) {
    case NSDraggingContextOutsideApplication:
        return NSDragOperationCopy | NSDragOperationDelete;
        break;     
    case NSDraggingContextWithinApplication:    
    default:
        return NSDragOperationMove;
        break;
}
}
```

Yet it is never called, and when

```
- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView*)tv
            validateDrop:(id )info
             proposedRow:(NSInteger)row
   proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)op
{
    return NSDragOperationMove ;
}
```

`- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView*)tv
       acceptDrop:(id )info
              row:(NSInteger)row
    dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)op`

are called, po info yields:

SDraggingInfo: draggingSequenceNumber=0x74000000 draggingDestinationWindow= draggingSourceOperationMask=0x11 draggingLocation={96.49609375, 192.7421875} draggingPasteboard=

draggingSourceOperationMask=0x11 indicates both copy and move are allowed.

I can't seem to control which operations are allowed.

Why isn't draggingSession... called?

Many thanks

EDIT:

Does NSTableView set itself or its data source as the draggingSource when it calls:

`dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack`

Answer (score 0):

The NSTableView sets itself as the draggingSource which means the NSTableView's dataSource never sees the call to dragImage...  I established this by placing a dummy dragImage... method in the NSTableView.